# drawtext options in Dev C++ for a win32 programme

Tags: c++, winapi

when i run this code, both 'first text' and 'second text' appear at the same location and are overlapped. any help ??

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR szCmdLine, int     iCmdShow)
{
static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("My Window") ;
HWND hwnd ;
MSG msg ;
WNDCLASS wndclass ;
wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc ;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0 ;
wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0 ;
wndclass.hInstance = hInstance ;
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW+0;//DISPLAYS GREY BACKGROUND OF CLIENT AREA
wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL ;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;
if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
{
MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Window not Registered"),
szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
return 0 ;
}
hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, // window class name
TEXT ("MC090203908"), // window caption
WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, // window style
CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial x position
CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial y position
400,300,
NULL, // parent window handle
NULL, // window menu handle
hInstance, // program instance handle
NULL) ; // creation parameters
ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;
while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
}
return msg.wParam ;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC hdc ;
PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
RECT rect ;
HRGN bgRgn;
HBRUSH hBrush;
HPEN hPen;
switch (message)
{
case WM_PAINT:
hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect) ;
DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("First text"), -1, &rect,DT_LEFT|DT_TOP) ;
DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("SECOND text"), -1, &rect,DT_LEFT) ;
EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
return 0 ;
case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage (0) ;
return 0 ;
}
return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

i want the second text to appear on the second line and on the left side of the window

Comment: Um, the value of `DT_TOP` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest using resource files (.rc) instead of paint, paint can be dangourus if not kept a close eye on. DT_TOP sounds to me like a z-sort flag rather than a x/y position, thus putting 'first text' overlaping 'second text' becuase they are both asigned the DT_LEFT flag (which gives them the same position on the window.)

Its much esayer to work with .rc files, as you can specify they're exact coordinates on the window. and they are alot more stable.

This is where I learned my win32 from: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

I highly recomend going through it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've put them to overlap each other. (I think) it's default, if nothing specified for c++ to put the text in the top left corner.
i would recommend remapping the rect passed to the second DrawText() to something a little more below.

```
DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("First text"), -1, &rect,DT_LEFT|DT_TOP) ;
rect.top = 24;  // 24 pixels below
DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("SECOND text"), -1, &rect,DT_LEFT) ;
rect.top = 0;   // change it back to 0, so the rect will be just as before
```

testet and works ;)

Comment: Even though it's not really an optimal solution, but it's easy.